# Cannot orient my replacement Badger waste disposal

Tags: garbage-disposal

I'm trying to replace my 3/4 hp badger insinkerator with an ideantical one.
The top flange with ramps used to be free to rotate freely, the new one has small tab part of the flange that fits in a casing notch and doesn't allow it to rotate, only a few degrees.
My problem is that now I cannot orient the drain to the old position (straigt out the back) because when mounting the unit I can't rotate it to the proper orientation.
Any suggestions?  Can I simply use the old flange?

[image: New flange with metal stop]

[image]

Comment: Is there a new mounting ring with the new disposal that accommodates this little tab? Maybe you need to use it instead of reusing the old one. I know, I like to not remove and reinstall nearly identical parts either...

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! Please write this up as an answer (self-answers are not only allowed, they're encouraged), then give it a check mark when the system will allow it. That way future readers can easily determine that this has a workable solution - it makes it easier for them.

Comment: "...then give it a check mark" <----------- that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can confirm. A new Insinkerator Badger 5 purchased 08/23/2023 works with an existing 8+ year old original collar in the sink. The weird thing is they changed the design at some point to add a little tab on the lower collar which is somewhat flummoxing when comparing the the new disposal with the old one. As others have said above, once you get the collar on you can then spin the disposal around so the plumbing fits. Depending on your configuration you might have to attach the discharge tube after you have the disposal in place. Hilarious that the accepted answer is "grind the tab off". Did Tim the Tool Guy write that one?

Answer (score 3):

The mounting ring on the drain is identical to the old one. I ended up using the old flange and it's fine.
However, I'm still puzzled about how would I be able to orient the unit if I had used the flange the comes with it ...
Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I had this exact issue and thought I was out of my mind that there was nothing about it on insinkerator's site or in videos, aside from this question. Replacing the flange did the trick.

Comment: I've always been able to turn the Insinkerator's body to suit even after it has been mounted and the ring locked. Even easier if you lube the gasket with some silicone grease first.

Answer (score 2):

The new ones use the "Lift and Lock" system to ease the installation. The lug and notch combo holds the locking ring to the disposer so you can now use TWO hands (MUCH easier) to hold and line up the disposer to the sink assembly and then turn the disposal clockwise which will also run the locking ring up the ramps. Much easier to do. Then using the Wrenchette or whatever way you wish to complete the locking ring install, the locking ring will now disengage that "cursed" lug from the disposal body and allow it to rotate into position for the drain plumbing. The ring lifts up out of engagement with the body. It took me quite a while to understand this as it also was most likely with a lot of installers since that issue is not made clear in the written instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too. Once you screw the entire unit onto the sink, it will compress the rubber seal and give you enough space to rotate the disposal and orient it. This means you need to either remove the drain trap before installing and then reconnect it afterward, or attach the discharge tube to the disposal after connecting it to the sink. I decided to do the latter since I was having a hard time removing the drain trap.

Comment: I tried this, but had no luck -- even when the unit was fully locked in under the sink, I couldn't get it to rotate so I could orient it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today.  First hold the disposal up to the bracket then twist the whole disposal clockwise a little bit.  Don’t worry about alignment yet.  After that the ring will turn freely and you can orient the disposal before turning the ring by itself to lock it in.  It’s confusing but actually an improvement to the old way where you had to push it up so hard into the rubber gasket to get it started.

Comment: I already fixed it  months ago.  Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: THIS HAS BEEN RESOLVED

Comment: @JMCarr - although you originally asked the question, the Stack Exchange model is intended to be useful for others who might have similar questions in the future. New answers from others who might have a different perspective are encouraged as they could address someone else's situation which could be slightly different to yours.

Comment: Thanks @brhans.
How do I stop getting notifications on this thread?

Comment: Had the same problem today and found this thread.   Step 23 of the instructions say to do what Tom Biby discovered on his own: " Step 23  (1) hang disposer by aligning 3 mounting tabs with slide-up ramps on mounting ring and (2) SLIGHTLY turn disposal clockwise. Step 24 Turn mounting ring until all 3 mounting tabs latch over the ridges on the slide-up ramps", It appears the problem the rest of us were having was that we all "knew" how to install the disposal based on prior experience so did not benefit from the improved design by carefully reading the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this "problem" as well. I was upgrading from 1/3 hp to 3/4 hp and thought there may be differences that I was not aware in terms of mounting. But I decided to search the web anyway. Good thing, as I came to this exchange and I followed Tom Biby's answer and that was "the answer" for my situation. I did add a little silicone grease just before mounting to keep things from possibly sticking. Once you twist the disposal, it appears to click into place and I was easily about to rotate the disposal afterwards. I'm glad I didn't do something else that would have taken more time and been less effective. Too bad the instructions do not appear to contain this tip or FYI. At least I didn't see it in the instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use old locking flange or grind off tab on new one. Why are they changing this anyway.